# Shell script to copy a specific file from one folder to another with date

Tags: scripts

I want to write a script which look for a specific file in a specific folder. file name and location will be pre-define in the script. A loop will run, if the file exist, it will copy that file to another location with date on it(this location will also be define), and if the file does not exist, it will give a pop up with "File does not exist"
I have tried with this:

```
srcdir="/home/bmsc/HOME/oam/data"
dstdir="/home/bmsc/backup"
source=/home/bmsc/HOME/data/haguard.xml
destination=/home/bmsc/backup/
d=$(date +%m%d%y)

for srcfile in ${srcdir}/*
do
    dstfile=$(basename $srcfile)
    dstfile=${dstfile/\./${d}\.}
    cp "$source" "$dstdir/$dstfile"
done
```

But its coping all the files in srcdir. Please can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a specific file, why run a loop? You can directly test for the existence of that file:

```
if [[ -f $source ]]
then
    dstfile=$(basename "$source")
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked for me. I do have one more query. If I want to copy the whole content of a file 'say as haguard.xml' which is with me to the location with the same name /home/bmsc/HOME/data/haguard.xml

Comment: @saketgupta I don't understand. Do you want to copy `say as haguard.xml` to  `/home/bmsc/HOME/data/haguard.xml`? Just do `cp "say as haguard.xml" /home/bmsc/HOME/data/haguard.xml`.

Comment: it will be the flow of same script. i have taken the backup of file haguard.xml in directory backup with the date mentioned on it. suppose the file created in backup directory is haguard.xml121014. now i have made some changes in the file haguard.xml121014. now in the script i want to replace all the content of haguard.xml with the contents in haguard.xml121014. but the file name will be same as data/haguard.xml

Comment: @saketgupta so you could do `cp ${dstdir}/haguard.xml* ${srcdir}/haguard.xml` (assuming there's only backup copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
srcdir="/home/bmsc/HOME/oam/data"
dstdir="/home/bmsc/backup"
source=/home/bmsc/HOME/data/haguard.xml
destination=/home/bmsc/backup/
d=$(date +%m%d%y)

if [ -f $source]; then
      dstfile=$(basename $source)
      dstfile=${dstfile/\./${d}\.}
      cp "$source" "$dstdir/$dstfile"
fi
```